# How to save parsed JSON data temporarily?

Tags: json, swift, storage

In my app currently, I'm successfully making a POST call to web API and getting access token and its expiration time from JSON.

Now I want to save access token that's one of the objects in JSON that I'm parsing. However, I want to save it temporarily. Meaning, user will need to log back in to get another access token in order to use the app.

I've read materials about core data but all of them use permanent storage. I've also looked at Locksmith but I don't think that's about storing temporarily either.

Please help! What approach is available?

Here's the parsed JSON I'm using and I need access token displayed below:

```
 var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

 if let parseJSON = json {
      var token = parseJSON["access_token"] as? String
      println("token: \(token)")
 }
```

Comment: Temporary is subjective.  You could write it to any store, whether its CoreData or to `NSUserDefaults` and name it such that your application logic understands it is "temporary".

Comment: Do you mean caching it in just memory and not in disk?

Comment: archive it into the `NSCacheDirectory` if the memory is not temporary enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you want to store this access token only whilst the app is running. If the app is closed then you want your user to log back in, therefore getting a new token? If that's the case then i would simply use a variable to store it e.g. in a UserManager singleton class or possibly in your app delegate if you like.

If you want to store this variable for longer e.g. if you want to store it even if the app has been closed then I would use NSUserDefaults to store it. The only issue with storing it in the userDefaults is that it isn't very secure as this is a plist that can be read by anyone. So for this reason I wouldn't suggest storing it as a string, I would store it as data instead.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() 
if token != nil {
    let tokenData = token!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    defaults.setObject(tokenData, forKey: "accessToken")
}
```

Feel free to change the key "accessToken" to anything else, even a random string of numbers and digits as you will then have some security through obfuscation. To retrieve the access token from NSUserDefaults, use the following code:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var token: String?
if let tokenData = defaults.objectForKey("accessToken") as? NSData {
    token = NSString(data: tokenData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String
}
```

Using these techniques you could then go ahead and make a property that will do all of this for you which would make it a lot more convenient to use:

```
//MARK: Variables 
private var tokenKey = "asdfa4tet4qtqERfasfQW$Rwrwe" //Random characters to hide the key.

//MARK: Properties
var Token: String? {

    get {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var token: String?
        if let tokenData = defaults.objectForKey(self.tokenKey) as? NSData {
            token = NSString(data: tokenData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String
        }
        return token
    }
    set(token)  {

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if token != nil {
            var tokenData = token!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
            defaults.setObject(tokenData, forKey: self.tokenKey)
        } else {
            defaults.setObject(nil, forKey: self.tokenKey)
        }  
    } 

}
```